# Cannot resolve symbol 'database' in net.sqlcipher import in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlcipher, cannot-find-symbol, sqlcipher-android

Any idea why I am having this cannot resolve symbol 'database' in `net.sqlcipher`. I simply cloned [SQLCipher Android Test](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests) from GitHub and wanted to test.

have also attached the screenshot for reference.
[image]

Thank you...

Comment: sync gradle, clean & rebuild project

Comment: Share your gradle

Comment: this will be its gradle https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests/master/build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to compile now after I've added compileOptions as JavaVersion 8 and enabled JACK

```
compileOptions {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Jack Options is added inside `defaultConfig`

```
jackOptions {
  enabled true
}
```

Now my `app/build.gradle` has become like this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.zetetic.sqlcipher.test"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    jackOptions {
     enabled true
    }
 }
buildTypes {
 release {
  minifyEnabled false
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
 }
}

compileOptions {
 sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

// For testing zip-based distributions:
//compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')


 // For testing AAR packages:
 compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.9@aar'
}
```

Thanks a lot for your helps guys.

Comment: Glad to see you fixed. You can disable `jackOptions`.I thought you added JAVA 8. Read https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#configure-gradle

Comment: yes. mine was in Gradle 2. after i've upgraded to Gradle 3, I am able to remove `jackOptions`

Answer (score 0):

```
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper;
```

**DON'T**

```
import android.database.Cursor;
```

**DO**

```
 import net.sqlcipher.Cursor;
```

You should use

For **`app/build.gradle`** section

```
   compile (name: 'android-database-sqlcipher-3.5.9', ext: 'aar')
```

Add below project's **`build.gradle`** file

```
  repositories {
     jcenter()
    }
```

Then **`File-> Sync Project with Gradle Files`** & **`Clean->Rebuild Project`**.

Read [**`SQLCipher for Android Application Integration`**](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/)

**FYI**

> We initially tested adding Java 8 support via the Jack toolchain. Over
>   time, we realized the cost of switching to Jack was too high for our
>   community when we considered the annotation processors, bytecode
>   analyzers and rewriters impacted. Thank you for trying the Jack
>   toolchain and giving us great feedback. You can continue using Jack to
>   build your Java 8 code until we release the new support. Migrating
>   from Jack should require little or no work.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Comment: oh, I am still using older version of Gradle. so it's `compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.9@aar` instead of `implementation`. The rest is the same.

Comment: @MinSoe at first import `import net.sqlcipher.Cursor;`

Comment: it's the same. there's nothing under `net.sqlcipher`

Comment: @MinSoe add `compile (name: 'android-database-sqlcipher-3.5.9', ext: 'aar')`

Comment: @MinSoe After change Restart your IDE.